# AttributeError in the implementation of queue by using Single Linked List in the python

Tags: python, queue, singly-linked-list, enqueue

I want to implement a queue by using a single linked list. When I run the below code, I receive the AttributeError. I don't know what should I do to fix this issue.
I assume the first of the linked list as a front and the of that as a rear of the queue.
by using the while loop I wanted to concatenate the whole single linked list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.info = value
        self.link = None


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.front = None


    def enqueue(self, data):
        temp = Node(data)
        p = self.front
        if self.front is None:
            self.front = temp

        while p.link is not None:
            p = p.link
        p.link = temp
        temp.link = None

    def dequeue(self):
        self.front = self.front.link

    def size(self):
        p = self.start
        n = 0
        while p is not None:
            p = p.link
            n += 1
        return n

    def display(self):
        p = self.start
        while p is not None:
            p = p.link
        print(p.info, '', end='')

qu = Queue()

for i in range(4):
    add = int(input("please enter the elements "))
    qu.enqueue(add)
    qu.display()

for i in range(2):
    qu.dequeue()
    qu.display()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Music/Queue_SLList.py", line 43, in <module>
    qu.enqueue(add)
  File "C:/Users/HP/Music/Queue_SLList.py", line 18, in enqueue
    while p.link is not None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'link'
```

Comment: `p = self.front` needs to be *after* the `if` that sets `self.front`

Comment: Here you are @Barmar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Music/Queue_SLList.py", line 43, in <module>
    qu.enqueue(add)
  File "C:/Users/HP/Music/Queue_SLList.py", line 18, in enqueue
    while p.link is not None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'link'

Comment: Put it in the question so it can be formatted readably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the queue is empty, you set `p` to `None` when you do `p = self.front`.  Then you get an error when you try to do `while p.link is not None` because `p` isn't a node.

You should just return from the method in the case where you're enqueuing the first noe.

```
    def enqueue(self, data):
        temp = Node(data)
        if self.front is None:
            self.front = temp
            return

        p = self.front
        while p.link is not None:
            p = p.link
        p.link = temp
        temp.link = None
```